# Ввод информации в textfield

Tags: java

Есть форма, на которой созданы Textfield, две кнопки и два Label, т.е. форма входа. Указание логина и пароля. Как сделать, чтобы если поле логина пустое, то выдавало сообщение на подобии "Вы не ввели логин"?

Созданная форма

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setBounds(400,200,500,400);
    this.setTitle("Вход");
    Container cont1 = this.getContentPane();
    cont1.setLayout(null);
    cont1.add(btn1);
    btn1.setSize(150,50);
    btn1.setLocation(350,310);
    btn1.addActionListener(new Listik());
    cont1.add(btn2);
    btn2.setSize(150,50);
    btn2.setLocation(0,310);
    btn2.addActionListener(new Better());
    cont1.add(tf1);
    tf1.setSize(190,25);
    tf1.setLocation(250,100);
    cont1.add(tf2);
    tf2.setSize(190,25);
    tf2.setLocation(250,159);
    cont1.add(lbl1);
    lbl1.setSize(100,30);
    lbl1.setLocation(100,90);
    cont1.add(lbl2);
    lbl2.setSize(100,30);
    lbl2.setLocation(100,150);
    cont1.add(rbtn1);
    rbtn1.setSize(200,30);
    rbtn1.setLocation(222,200);
```

Для `btn1` я уже сделал событие вызов пустой формы, но если будет пустое поле или не правильно введенные данные чтобы эта форма не открывалась, а показывалось сообщение об ошибке

Comment: ваш код в студию

Comment: Уже исправил)))

Comment: Да этот код совсем не нужен. Код, где у вас не получается что-то

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Повесьте нечто на событие нажатия на кнопку

```
if (null == textLogin.getText() || textLogin.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "текст ошибки", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
} else {
    //Вызов вышей формы
}
```

где `textLogin` - это ваш компонент `JTextEdit`, содержащий логин

Comment: Спасибо большое) Работает))